# Where is the first track of Toaru Kagaku no Railgun S OST 2 first played?

Tags: music, a-certain-scientific-railgun

[The OST](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Toaru_Kagaku_no_Railgun_S_Original_Soundtrack_2) in question can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75dFt2STxIk). I'm looking for where it was played in the anime.

The title says "Saijaku VS Saikyou (最弱 VS 最強)," which translates to "Weakest vs Strongest," but I don't seem to hear it in Touma vs Accelerator's battle.

Answer (score 1):

this song was featured on the Railgun S OST but it first appeared in "a certain magical index", episode 14 which was actually titled the same as the song, "strongest vs weakest", viewable here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NV2fR2cdRQ
but since your post does request when it appears in relevance to the Railgun series that would be episode 4 when Touma is fighting Misaka under the bridge at night. here's a clip of it directly from funimation's official channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lEtG-CJ9IY 
in the Railgun S series it was swapped for the soundtrack from OST volume 2 #16 "Ketsui to kakugo" in the Touma vs Accelerator fight which took place in episode 15.

Answer (score 0):

It plays when Accelerator is fighting Touma(In Saijaku vs Saikyou E14). Forward to around **4 minute 30 second** mark and you'll see it's not very emphatic but yeah gives the fight some taste.